# Yii2 CRUD, many controllers needed?

Tags: routes, yii2, crud

This feels definitely like a beginner question of designing a Yii2 project. 
I have a project of many different parts. 
For each one of these parts I have used CRUD, and I let it generate all files in the views directory. I can pick what I need from it, I resonated.
I did also generate separate Controller files for each.
Obviously, when the user is working with anything regarding the different parts, I will always need to check user-related stuff; whether he/she is correctly logged in, has the rights etc, but that logic is in siteController, and it seems not to be called when I have my newly generated controllers. 
Can i route it some way, so it always goes through siteController before anything else?

Comment: to chek user-related stuff and logged in , you can use behavior

Comment: or you can use beforeAction method in every controller

Comment: Thank you. Gives me an idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is create a generic controller, let's say `FrontendController`, and implement there the methods you will be using in all the other controllers. Then, inherit those controllers from that `FrontendController` and you'll have all those methods available.

Comment: Thank you! Or can I just let my controllers derive from siteController?

Comment: Hmmm. Then all your controllers will inherit all your SiteController actions, which I think it is unnecessary

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you're correct!
But then, what I obviously need everywhere is the "behaviours" function.
I could lift that one out from SiteController, place it in your supposed  FrontendController,
and then let all my controllers - SiteController included - derive from that one?

Comment: That is exactly what I was suggesting, yes